# How to seperate base URL and endpoint in laravel http client api call?

Tags: php, laravel, api, http, guzzle

Like in guzzle, I want to seperate base URL and end point

```
use Guzzle\Http\Client;
use Guzzle\Stream\PhpStreamRequestFactory;

$client = new Client('https://stream.twitter.com/');//base url

$request = $client->post('statuses/2',123);//end point
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. It has a method called `baseUrl()`.

Laravel provides an expressive, minimal API around the [Guzzle HTT](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/)P client, allowing you to quickly make outgoing HTTP requests to communicate with other web applications.

```
 $response = Http::baseUrl("https://reqres.in/api")->get('users');
```

Another way is to create [macros](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client#macros) .Define the macro within the boot method of your application's `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider class:`

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        
        Http::macro('reqres', function () {
            return Http::baseUrl('https://reqres.in/api');
        });
    }
}
```

and now you can reuse this method like below.

```
 $response  = Http::reqres()->get('users');
```

For post method

```
 $response  = Http::reqres()->post('users',[
        "name"=> "morpheus",
        "job"=> "leader"
    ]);
```

There are lots of built-in methods, which you can refer to here [HTTP Client](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client#introduction)

Dont forget to import facades

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
```

---

If you want to use [Guzzle](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html?highlight=base%20url#creating-a-client) then

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'https://reqres.in/api/']);

$response = $client->request('GET', 'users');
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want something like this?

```php
$client = Http::baseUrl("https://stream.twitter.com/");
$response2 = $client->post('statuses/2',["status"=>"success"]);
$response3 = $client->post('statuses/3',["status"=>"success"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Guzzle uses [guzzle/psr7](https://github.com/guzzle/psr7) to do this. You can too (I think any PSR7 implementation would do not just Guzzle's since PSR7 is a standard):

```
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri;

$uri = new Uri('https://stream.twitter.com/');
$uriWithPath = $uri->withPath('statuses/2');
```

Keep in mind that `Uri` is an immutable class therefore all mutating operations create a new instance of Uri with the additional property you need.